# is it possible to sort non facet attribute in solr Hybris?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

Scenario:
Product having 4 fields (rolling start date1, rolling start date2, rolling end date1,rolling end date2)

At front end all these columns are separate and  based on user click it should be sorted either asc/desc.

how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this is just another visualisation of the `SolrSort` objects from SAP Commerce. Out of the box, they are displayed in a drop down list

Instead of this list, you could attach this to a click on a column header to set that sort. The implementation depends a bit on how you visualize your table, or what library you use.

For the sort itself, when you are using the accelerator storefront, a click on the column header could change the sorting parameter in the url. For example `?sort=name-asc`

For spartacus projects, it's something similar to send to the backend api's